# Network Solutions Cron Job

Tags: php, mysqli, cron

So I created this PHP file with the following mysqli code to run a few scripts on my database every 30 minutes.  I can open this page on the site by typing in the url and it runs fine but when I set it up as a cron job on my network solutions cron tab it fails every time.  I get the following error messages and I can't seem to find the answer im looking for on here with other questions.  The server name is correct because it runs normally if i run it manually.

Failed to connect to MySQL: Can't connect to mysql server 'mysqlcluster7'

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("mysqlcluster7","test","xxxxxx","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT IGNORE INTO tblvenueimg (v_location) SELECT location FROM events GROUP BY location");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events INNER JOIN tblvenueimg ON events.location = tblvenueimg.v_location SET events.venueimg = tblvenueimg.v_locimage");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tblmusic (soundcloudprof, name, username) SELECT t.musicprof, t.musicprof, t.musicprof FROM (SELECT musicprof
from events where musicprof <> ' ' group by musicprof) as t
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE soundcloudprof = t.musicprof, name = t.musicprof, username = t.musicprof");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events INNER JOIN tblmusicfeatured ON events.user_name = tblmusicfeatured.username SET events.musicprof = tblmusicfeatured.soundcloudprof");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events SET trending ='2' WHERE location LIKE '%boston%'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events SET trending ='2' WHERE location LIKE '%allston%'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events SET trending ='2' WHERE location LIKE '%cambridge%'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events INNER JOIN tblfeatureddj ON events.id_user = tblfeatureddj.id_user SET trending ='3'");
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE events SET trending ='4' WHERE profimg LIKE '%017.jpg%'");

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You probably need to use a fully-qualified name, `mysqlcluster7.somedomain.com`

Comment: i tried that but its refusing a connection and it won't even work when i run it manually in that case.

Comment: If it refuses the connection, it means that either the MySQL server isn't running, or there's a firewall blocking your client.

Comment: side note: a number of those queries could be combined

Comment: i know, for now I just put all the queries into one file but they will be combined.

Comment: I know this  is old, but I have the same issue. I have also tried localhost and 127.0.0.1. Seems like another weak point with NS.